# Instead of using position in OnItemClick how can i use view to filter Strings in android Studio?

Tags: listview, android-activity, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

i have used position for filtering the strings. as code below

```
String p = words[position];
String[] description = getResource().getStringArray(R.array.description_string_array);final String deslable=description[position];
Intent i = new Intent(Mainactivity.this, Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("wordname", p);
i.putExtra("deslable",deslable);
startActivity(i);
```

while searching the text i was getting first index instead of corresponding index in the description layout. therefore, anyone please tell me how to fix it. or is there any other method to do this? thanks

Comment: How do you determine the value of `position`? Did you make sure it is not 0?

Comment: position means array index, so while i search any text like 'good' it must show the description of good but the description layout showing starting index like `a` and `an` etc, it doesn't show me corresponding  description layout index. your kind help meant me lots. thanks

Comment: I know that position means the index in the array, but how do you set its value? Where is the line of code that says something like `position = ...`